# React Routing not working(Gives blank page on running application)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

On running the application I get a blank display without errors. It does not route to root or to home page. Could someone please help me with this as this is the first time I have tried react route.

Below is my code:

index.js

```
var React=require('react');
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import {Header} from './components/Header';
import {Home} from './components/Home';
import {Root} from './components/Root';


class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path={"/"} component={Root}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        </Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

Root.js

```
var React=require('react');

import {Header} from "./Header";
import {Home} from "./Home";

class Root extends React.Component{
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";

export class Home extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div id="test">
        <p>
          This is a new app. testing
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of react router are you using? last i checked, later versions no longer supported nested rooutes

Comment: I used version 4.2.0.  Even if i use a single route component it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pasting this over your entire `index.js` file content.

```
// React.
import React from 'react'

// DOM.
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

// React Router DOM.
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'

// Root.
import {
  Root
} from './components/Root';

// Home.
import {
  Home
} from './components/Home';

// Render.
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Root>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
      </Switch>
    </Root>
  </Router>
, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

I would personally import using [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) across the board, rather than `require`. You seem to have a strange combination of the two strategies.

Also, your `Root.js` file doesn't appear to have an [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) statement.

Finally, I can't check for sure since the site is currently down, but I have a feeling that since `React Router v4` components are now all imported from `'react-router-dom'` rather than `'react-router'`. `<IndexRoute/>` might no longer even be a thing.

Comment: thank you for the reply...but after making the changes i get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Comment: Ahahah. My bad. I forgot to include the ReactDOM import. It's there now. Should be all good.

Comment: You may need to install it as a dependency. I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you..it works perfectly fine now....just had another question..how can i perform nested routes with react router v4?

Comment: See [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy/nested-routes)